# How Can Convert Time in 24 h to 12 h in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have Table In Power BI

Contain Time Column (10:12:2 AM) its datatype is Time,
I want to split column contains Just (hour) from Time Column ,

I used Time.Hour() and it does work but in 24h, I want to make the new column 12h

8:10:9 PM ==>  8 PM not 20 ,
8:10:9 AM ==>  8 AM

How can I do it

Comment: You can use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax) to convert a time to 12-hrs. format.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery - use:

```
Time.ToText(#time(8, 10, 9), [Format="hh tt"])
```